# Перечеркивается ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-studio

Недавно обновил Android Studio. При создании проекта  сразу же перечеркивается ActionBarActivity, как показано на скрине. В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C релиза `suport.v7.AppCompat 22.1` `ActionBarActivity` объявлена `deprecated` (устаревшей), вместо нее предлагается использовать совсем новую `AppCompatActivity`, которая реализует несколько новых плюшек, вроде поддержки material-стиля для некоторых обычных виджетов (`Button`, `Checkbox` и пр.)

Ничего страшного не случится, даже если вы будете продолжать использовать `ActionBarActivity`. Deprecated это не ошибка, а предупреждение о том, что метод\класс заменен более новым.
Хотя существует довольно малая вероятность, что когда-нибудь этот класс будет вовсе удален из API и тогда уже будет ошибка из за отсутствующего класса.

[Подробности](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/LNyDnnBYJ8r)

Comment: Спасибо!
А почему просто нельзя наследоваться от Activity? Или это только ради "новых плюшек"?

Comment: Вы вполне можете наследоваться от `Activity` - этот класс не объявлен  deprecated :) , если вам не нужно то, что несет в себе библиотека поддержки `AppCompat`

Answer (score 0):

Вам же человеческим языком пишут: этот класс устарел.

Перечеркиваются идентификаторы, которые были объявлены с аннотацией @Deprecated.